# Relations counting in two sets

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have two sets $A=\{1,2,3, 4\}, \ B=\{5,6,7,8,9\}$.
I wanted to count the relations from $A$ to $B$ that didn't include $1$ in their domain.
First i did it like this:

> $2^{20} - 2^5 + 1  = 1048545$

since $2^{20}$ is the number of all relations, $2^5$ is the number of relations from $\{1\}$ to B and plus $1$ cause $2^5$ includes the empty relation which i need.
This is a bit weird cause it means $99\%$ of all relations do not include $1$ in their domain which i think is odd.

So i tried another method, i said lets look at $A$ like $A=\{2,3,4\}$ and now we have

> $2^{15} = 32768$

relations which contains all except 1.
I liked this solution more but still it looks a bit odd to me, do only $32768$ relations out of $104k+$ relations do not include 1 in their domain? so little?

So i'm stuck between these two methods, maybe i'm wrong in both :D
Can someone enlighten me? :)

Comment: In the first method you are only deducing the subsets of $\left\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)\right\}$. But once you have $(1,3)$, for example, in your relation you could also add other $2$-tuples, but your first method is not deducing those cases. Try your methods with $A\left\{1,2\right\}$ and $B=\left\{3\right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

How many options do you have for the image of $1$?, how many options for the remaining elements of $A$?

Full solution:

> There is only one option for the image of $1$, the empty set. The other 3 elements of $A$ have $2^5$ options, giving you he answer of $2^{15}$, which is what you had. This solution make sense, because from every relation between sets $\{2,3,4\}$ and $B$ you can create $2^5$ relations between $A$ and $B$ simply by changing the image of $\{1\}$

Comment: Your 2^15 should be 2^{15}. (This was my first attempted outside edit - I guess the site requires more "substantial" edits!)

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. Thank you very much.